# FFMPEG H.264 encoding under Win10 with several AMD RX580 cards

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, h.264, video-encoding, amf

I need to encode about eight videos at a time to H.264 on eight AMD RX580 GPUs on Win10. What I'm looking for is to how to assign each ffmpeg to particular GPU. I can't find any flag/options to set this.

Current test works well but it picks the first GPU all the time:

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -c:v h264_amf -movflags +faststart -b:a 128k -c:a aac test.mkv
```

If you have a better idea on how to encode several videos in paralel with AMD GPU HW acceleration on Win please tell me. The ffmpeg or amf codec isn't a must. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424350/how-to-specify-the-gpu-to-be-used-by-nvenc-in-ffmpeg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to specify the GPU to be used by nvenc in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424350/how-to-specify-the-gpu-to-be-used-by-nvenc-in-ffmpeg)